# Click on any other cell while a cell of same row of datagridvew is in edit mode causes Operation is not valid reentrant call

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, datagridview

My question is similar to below, except that i dont know whats the alternative.

> [Why is my bound DataGridView throwing an "Operation not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114668/why-is-my-bound-datagridview-throwing-an-operation-not-valid-because-it-results)

When user finishes editing, the datagridview should refresh and display only those records which satisfy the gird's dataview criteria. so at the end of EndEdit i call doubleClick event of a control which populates the grid again according to the criteria. this approach works fine as long as the edit is complete. but if the user is still in edit mode & any other cell of the **same** datagridview is clicked i get this exception.

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>   SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

every other control is good because grid is out of edit mode. I have tried:

```
datagridview.CancelEdit();
```

before assigning the datasource to the grid again, but it gives the same exception.

Comment: Found the answer folks:

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893752/invalidoperationexception-when-ending-editing-a-cell-moving-to-another-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh the grid a-sync using

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Refresh_dataGridView1));
```

that should solve the problem. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893752/invalidoperationexception-when-ending-editing-a-cell-moving-to-another-cell)