# Tab to the next cell in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a number of cells that have their ReadOnly property set to True.

When the user tabs through the cells using the tab key I want to move the focus onto the next cell if the ReadOnly property is true. My code is below:

```
    private void filterGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!filterGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
        {
            EditCell(sender, e);                
        }
        else
        {
            //Move to the next cell
            filterGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Selected = true;
        }            
    }
```

However, when I run the above code I receive the following error:

Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

I'm using C# 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to do some user-testing, first. That could be very disconcerting during data entry.

Comment: I will once I get this to work!

Answer (score 3):

I use a derived DataGridView for stuff like this, this will only affect the Tab key so the user can still click on the readonly cell to copy-paste it etc.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    class MyDGV : DataGridView
    {
        public bool SelectNextCell()
        {
            int row = CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int column = CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            DataGridViewCell startingCell = CurrentCell;

            do
            {
                column++;
                if (column == Columns.Count)
                {
                    column = 0;
                    row++;
                }
                if (row == Rows.Count)
                    row = 0;
            } while (this[column, row].ReadOnly == true && this[column, row] != startingCell);

            if (this[column, row] == startingCell)
                return false;
            CurrentCell = this[column, row];
            return true;
        }

        protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
                return SelectNextCell();
            return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
        }

        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if ((keyData & Keys.KeyCode) == Keys.Tab)
                return SelectNextCell();
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the two suggestion should work

Use

```
 else
        {
            filterGrid.ClearSelection();
            filterGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Selected = true;
        }
```

[Otherwise one other method is suggested here along with the reason](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/7970b78b-4fb6-4138-b49e-fc3e665f866c) 
Also this one implies the same issue:-
[InvalidOperationException - When ending editing a cell & moving to another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893752/invalidoperationexception-when-ending-editing-a-cell-moving-to-another-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can use datagridview cell Enter event and bypass readonly cells tab index to another cell. Here is my example:-

```
    private void dgVData_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgVData.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
        }
    }
```